# Perform a function when radio button is clicked angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 radio button for gender as male and female. When iam clicking male button some action should be performed in controller. same with female button. But in my code only male button click is working. What is wrong i my code

Filter By:

```
        <label>

            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" 
            ng-model="Tofilter.sex" value="male" ng-click="checkStuff()" checked>
            <label for="gender" class="control-label col-xs-2">Male</label>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" 
            ng-model="Tofilter.sex" value="female" ng-click="checkStuff()">
            <label for="gender" class="control-label col-xs-2">Female</label>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ngChange` instead of `ngClick` (see [Angular input[radio] Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)).